# How do fix this display:flex like spacing in html

Tags: html, css

my school project website is like this [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loHRQ.png)
but i want the icons to align in one row becuase i want it to be like flexible for pc and smartphones and i find in the inspect [inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oigbt.png) can i like reduce the spacing of this?
the css of the icons is only like this

```
.icon {
    width: 10%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 0%;
    transition: all;
    transition: transform .2s;
}
.icons{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

icons is for the div and icon for the images

I did try configuring flex in the inspect but no avail

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, so I suspect your question will be closed soon, however, it sounds like what you might be looking for is media queries.  Media queries are typically used to add responsiveness to websites, by allowing you to specify different css when the browser width is at a certain threshold (usually at sizes used on mobile devices).  Read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: i just want the icons to be in one row for pc and the icons would be flexible for phones

Comment: And I provided the way you do that which is to add Media queries to your css file based on width.  Here's another resource for you to learn how to use them.  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-media-queries-breakpoints-media-types-standard-resolutions-and-more/.   Start with your PC based menu.  Add a media query aimed at phones, and inside of that override the css so that you have the css you want for the reduced menu.  There are various tools depending on the browser that you can use to help test this, but even without that you can just manually shrink the browser to test.

Comment: If you want icon in one row, then remove 'flex-wrap: wrap' this CSS property.

Comment: We can't really debug just CSS in isolation ... we also need the HTML which it works on. Please edit your question to make it clearer, make sure you describe in as much detail as possible what you want to happen versus what is actually happening, on each screen size, as well as include your HTML code.